# jquery/jquery-storageapi.js missing in Luma (Magento 2.0.3)

Tags: magento2, javascript

Chrome dev tools shows me this error:

> require.js:1895 GET
>   http://www.yy.ch/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/de_CH/jquery/jquery-storageapi.js

This file is not there: `jquery-storageapi.js`

I checked it on another Magento 2 installation, there it works and looks for:

```
jquery.storageapi.min.js
```

It also can't find `http://www.yy.ch/pub/static/_requirejs/frontend/yy/yy/de_CH/requirejs-config.js`

The File 14 kb is there, I can see it. But if I open that url in a browser it shows me: The "/home/zizzowa1/public_html/" file doesn't exist or not a file

It happen also in Magento 2.0.4, directly after installation without any change on it. And also in blank theme.

[image: Chrome Dev tools]

Comment: I'm having the same exact issues. Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this problem when using HTTPS. 
When using HTTPS an environment variable HTTPS="on" needs to be set. You can also set it as you run the static deploy command `HTTPS="on" php magento setup:static-content:deploy`.

I found this out from this forum answer https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2/404-s-Missing-JS-error-in-stock-Luma-Theme/td-p/30109#messageView2_4

Answer (score -1):

This appears to be a permission issue. Follow the steps on this page to fix: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html#install-perms-set

Answer (score -1):

You can follow below steps and it will be fix.

1) Set deploy mode to production - **php magento deploy:mode:set production**
       (js and css minification will works with production mode.If you are in developer mode with code minified above issues will show up as I experienced it. Also verify using echo the print_r($_SERVER) in index.php that production mode is set before load the website)

2) Clear all the caches setup in server

- **/etc/init.d/nginx restart**
- **/etc/init.d/php5.6-fpm restart**
- **/etc/init.d/varnish restart**

3) Clear the browser cache and view it in incognito mode. That's it!

Cheers!